# Insertion sort using binary search in python

Tags: python

I need a little help with the code below, I have been tasked with changing the insertion sort to use the given binary search function.

```
def binarySearch(aList, start, end, value): 
#Return the position where value is or should be inserted.

    while start <= end: 
        mid = (start + end) // 2 
        if aList[mid] == value: 
            return mid 
        if value < aList[mid]: 
            end = mid - 1 
        else: 
            start = mid + 1 
    return start

def insertionSort(aList):
#Sort aList in ascending order. 

    for index in range(1, len(aList)):
        key = aList[index]
        pos = index
        while pos > 0 and aList[pos - 1] > key:
            aList[pos] = aList[pos - 1]
            pos = pos - 1
        aList[pos] = key
```

The code I am using to test the function is:

```
numbers = [71, 32, 22, 19, 18, 1, 15, 40]
insertionSort(numbers)
print(numbers)
```

Any help is appreciated as I am having a mind blank

Comment: this code works, but the trouble im having is figuring out how to get the insertionSort function to use the binarySearch function

Comment: What a nonsensical task. After the pos is found, one still has to shift all the elements between pos and index, which the current implementation already does while looking for pos.

Comment: Binary search only works on a sorted list. Think about when/why a specific part of this list is sorted, and use that information. However, while this will reduce the number of comparisons, you still are performing the same number of swaps. And you don't gain much by using list insert, which is still O(n) https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity The algorithm remains fundamentally O(n**2) even if you replace one small part.

Comment: This very much looks like the M269 TMA02 question 1.c??? Anyway a list of size 1 is sorted that's where I would start...I prefer the recursive method to this, it reads a-lot better.

Answer (score 0):

```
def binary_search(arr, val, start, end):
    if start == end:    #折半到最后start和end可能会相等，递归退出条件之一
        if arr[start] > val:
            return start
        else:
            return start+1

    if start + 1 == end:    #折半到最后start和end相差1，递归退出条件之一
        return start+1

    mid = (start+end)//2
    if arr[mid] < val:
        return binary_search(arr,val,mid, end)
    elif arr[mid] > val:
        return binary_search(arr, val, start, mid)
    else:
        return mid   #折半遇到mid值与val相等，递归退出条件之一


def insertion_sort(arr:list):
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        if arr[i] <= arr[0]:
            index = 0
        elif arr[i] >= arr[i-1]:
            continue
        else:
            index = binary_search(arr[0:i],arr[i],0, i-1)
        arr = arr[:index]+ [arr[i]] + arr[index:i] + arr[i+1:]
    return arr

arr = [30,20,80,40,50,10,60,70,90]
insertion_sort(arr)
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution and just a note: while your code can fix the asker's issue, is always better to included a description of the code.